# How to switch only between editor windows (not tabs) in split mode

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

I frequently use the split editor window where I have some files in the left window and some in the right. How can I easily switch between these windows using only the keyboard?

There is a mapping on *Ctrl+Tab* that invokes the switcher. This however only works good if you have exactly one file open in each of the two windows. If you have more than one open Intellj Idea also wants to switch between the open tabs.

Comment: I didn't realize IntelliJ on Windows does not define a keyboard shortcut for this action by default (I use Mac, primarily, which does); see my updated answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What you want is "Goto next splitter" and "Goto previous splitter" under the menu "Window > Editor Tabs". On Mac OS X, they have predefined keyboard shortcuts:

- Mac <kbd>⌥⇥</kbd> (option, tab), <kbd>⌥⇧⇥</kbd> (option, shift, tab)

However, Windows does not have pre-define keyboard shortcuts, so you will have to make them yourself in "Preferences > Keymap" and assign your own short cut.

[image: Keymap preferences]

The trouble is finding one that does not conflict with an existing mapping; I've set mine to:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> for "Goto next splitter"
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> for "Goto prevous splitter"

[image: Setting the shortcut]